# How to handle alert or popup in Java appium automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I have been automating the FB application, after login, I am getting this pop-up, how to handle this in appium using java.

[image: FaceBook pop-up]

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the Alert class like this.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchto().alert
alert.accept(); // This will click the allow button
alert.dismiss(); // Or use this to click Deny button
```

Or handle it from the `id` of the ok button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id(“android:id/ok_button”)).click();
```